# Average of n numbers in java

Tags: java

Using loop I want to calculate the average of n numbers in Java and when user enters 0 the loop ends.
Here is the code that I have written:

```
public class start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an int value, the program exits if the input is 0");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int h = 0;
        while (input.nextInt() == 0){
            int inp = input.nextInt();
            int j = inp;
            int i = 0;
            h = j + i;
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("The total is: "+ h);
    }
}
```

Am I making any logical error?

Comment: Try tracing the program with real numbers. Then try running the program with real numbers. It sounds like you've done neither.

Comment: If you use a debugger to step through your code you will be able to see what each line of code does and understand you program. When the program behaves is a way you don't expect, this gives you a hint as to what you need to change to fix it. BTW: I would call my total variable `total` and I would use a `long` type to avoid underflow/overflows.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't name the sum h, but sum.
- The while-condition is wrong
- Why do you use inp and j and i?
- There is an unconditional break - why?
- You talk about the average. Do you know what the average is?
- Your output message is not about average - it is about the sum.

Answer (score 1):

"Am I making any logical error?"

Yes. This looks like a homework problem so I won't spell it out for you, but think about what the value of `i` is, and what `h = j + i` means in this case.

You also need to be careful about calling `input.nextInt()`. What will happen when you call it twice each time through the loop (which is what you are doing)?

Answer (score 1):

Homework, right?

Calling `input.nextInt()` in the while loop condition and also to fill in `int inp` means that each trip through the loop is reading two numbers (one of which is ignored). You need to figure out a way to only read one number per loop iteration and use it for both the `== 0` comparison as well as for `inp`.

Additionally, you've done the right thing having `h` outside the while loop, but I think you're confusing yourself with `j` and `i` inside the loop. You might consider slightly more descriptive names--which will make your code much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a counter of how many numbers you read so you can divide the total by this number to get the average.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the while loop:

```
while(true){
    int e=input.nextInt();
    if(e==0) break;
    h+=e;
    numberOfItems++;
}
```

Your original implementation called nextInt() twice, which has the effect of discarding every other number (which is definitely not what you intended to do).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you asking the user only once, to enter and if the number if zero you simply want to display the average. you need a variable declared outside the while loop that will keep adding different numbers entered by the user, along with a second variable which track the number of cases entered by the user and keep incrementing itself by one till number is not zero as entered by the user. And as the user Enters 0, the loop will break and here our Average will be displayed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopAverage
{
    public static void main(String[] args0)
    {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter any Integer value : ");
       int value = -1, sum = 0, count = 0;
       while((value = scan.nextInt()) != 0)
       {
         count++;
         sum = sum + value;
       }
       System.out.println("Average : " + (sum / count));
   }
}
```

Hope that might help,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

yes, oodles of logical errors.

- your while loop condition is wrong, you're consuming the first value
  you enter and unless that number is 0 you never enter the loop at all
- i var has no purpose
- you're breaking after one iteration
- you're not calculating a running total
- you're not incrementing a count for the average dividend
- you're not calculating an average
- This looks like you threw some code together and posted it.  The most
  glaring errors would have been found just by attempting to run it.

Some other things to consider:

- Make sure to check for divide by 0
- If you do an integer division, you might end up with an incorrect
  average, as it will be rounded.  Best to cast either the divisor or
  dividend to a float
- variable names should be helpful, get into the habit of using them

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to refer to the condition of "while" loop: if condition meets, what would the program do?
(If you know a little bit VB, what is the difference between do...until... and do...while...?)

Also, when you call scanner.nextInt(), what does the program do? For each input, how should you call it?

Last but not least, when should you use "break" or "continue"?

For the fundamentals, if you are in a course, recommend you to understand the notes. Or you can find some good books explaining details of Java. e.g. Thinking in Java

Enjoy learning Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.dev.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Average of N numbers
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Please enter the values to find out Average: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        
        int count = 1;
        
        while(count>0){
            if(n==0) {
                break;
            }else{
                sum = sum + n;
                count++;
                n = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        int avg = sum/(count-1);
        
        System.out.println("The Average of given numbers is "+ avg);
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).